# Undefined message in console while accessing json data using axios in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

We are building an e-commerce project using react-redux as a front-end language. Hence we have to display product categories in our application. So we use the Axios library to access JSON data from the server. Everything is working fine but when I console log response data then I get the undefined message.

Please help me to solve this problem...

**category component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

import Breadcrumb from "../../common/breadcrumb";
import { Slider6, Slider4 } from "../../../services/script";
import "react-tabs/style/react-tabs.scss";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class ElementCategory extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.categories);
    return (
      <div>
        <Breadcrumb parent={"Elements"} title={"Category"} />

        {/*Category One*/}
        <div className="container">
          <section className="section-b-space">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Slider {...Slider6} className="slide-6 no-arrow">
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat1.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>sport shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat2.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>casual shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat3.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>formal shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat4.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>flat</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat5.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>heels</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat6.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>boots</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat2.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>casual shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat3.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>casual shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Slider>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>

        {/*Category Two*/}
        <section className="p-0 ratio2_1">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row category-border">
              <div className="col-sm-4 border-padding">
                <div className="category-banner">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat1.png`}
                      className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-box">
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>men</h2>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 border-padding">
                <div className="category-banner">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat2.png`}
                      className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-box">
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>women</h2>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 border-padding">
                <div className="category-banner">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat3.png`}
                      className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-box">
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>kids</h2>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        {/*Category Three*/}
        <div className="container category-button">
          <section className="section-b-space">
            <div className="row partition1">
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  airbag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  burn bag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  briefcase
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  carpet bag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  money bag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  tucker bag
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>

        {/*Category Four*/}
        <div className="category-bg ratio_square">
          <div className="container-fluid p-0">
            <div className="row order-section">
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <a href="#" className="image-block">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat1.jpg`}
                    className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <div className="contain-block even">
                  <div>
                    <h6>new products</h6>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>zipper storage bag</h2>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-solid category-btn">
                      -80% off
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h6>
                        <span>shop now</span>
                      </h6>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <a href="#" className="image-block">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat2.jpg`}
                    className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <div className="contain-block">
                  <div>
                    <h6>on sale</h6>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>tucker bag</h2>
                    </a>{" "}
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-solid category-btn">
                      save 30% off
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h6>
                        <span>shop now</span>
                      </h6>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <a href="#" className="image-block even">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat3.jpg`}
                    className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <div className="contain-block">
                  <div>
                    <h6>summer sale</h6>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>gate check bag</h2>
                    </a>{" "}
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-solid category-btn">
                      minimum 50% off
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h6>
                        <span>shop now</span>
                      </h6>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/*Category Five*/}
        <section className="ratio_portrait">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Slider {...Slider4} className="slide-4 category-m no-arrow">
                  <div>
                    <div className="category-wrapper">
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <img
                            src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat1.png`}
                            className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </div>
                        <h4>watch models</h4>
                        <ul className="category-link">
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">d1 milano</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">damaskeening</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">diving watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">dollar watch</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                          view more
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div className="category-wrapper">
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <img
                            src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat2.png`}
                            className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </div>
                        <h4>calculator watch</h4>
                        <ul className="category-link">
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Shock-resistant watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Skeleton watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Slow watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Solar-powered watch</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                          view more
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-wrapper">
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat3.png`}
                          className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <h4>Antimagnetic watch</h4>
                      <ul className="category-link">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Watchmaking conglomerates</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Breitling SA</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Casio watches</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Citizen Watch</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                        view more
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-wrapper">
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat2.png`}
                          className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <h4>History of watches</h4>
                      <ul className="category-link">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Manufacture d'horlogerie</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Mechanical watch</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Microbrand watches</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">MIL-W-46374</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                        view more
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-wrapper">
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat1.png`}
                          className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <h4>watch models</h4>
                      <ul className="category-link">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">d1 milano</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">damaskeening</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">diving watch</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">dollar watch</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                        view more
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Slider>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        {/*Category Six*/}
        <section className="section-b-space">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row background">
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4 data-hover="size 06">size 06</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 07</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 08</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 09</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 10</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    categories: state.category,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ElementCategory);
```

**shop.js:**

```
/**
 * Mocking client-server processing
 */
import axios from "axios";
// import _products from './data.json'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import store from "../store";
import { receiveProducts } from "../actions/index";

const TIMEOUT = 100;

const _products = axios
  .get(`http://localhost:4000/product`)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });

const _category = axios
  .get(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });

export default {
  getProducts: (cb, timeout) =>
    setTimeout(() => cb(_products), timeout || TIMEOUT),
  getCategories: (cb, timeout) =>
    setTimeout(() => cb(_category), timeout || TIMEOUT),
  buyProducts: (payload, cb, timeout) =>
    setTimeout(() => cb(), timeout || TIMEOUT),
};
```

**action/index.js:**

```
import shop from "../api/shop";
import * as types from "../constants/ActionTypes";
import store from "../store";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css";

export const fetchProductsBegin = () => ({
  type: types.FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN,
});

export const receiveProducts = (products) => ({
  type: types.RECEIVE_PRODUCTS,
  products,
});

export const fetchCategoriesBegin = () => ({
  type: types.FETCH_CATEGORIES_BEGIN,
});

export const receiveCategories = (categories) => ({
  type: types.RECEIVE_CATEGORIES,
  categories,
});
export const getAllProducts = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchProductsBegin());
  return shop.getProducts((products) => {
    products.then((data) => {
      dispatch(receiveProducts(data));
    });
  });
};
export const getAllCategories = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchCategoriesBegin());
  return shop.getCategories((categories) => {
    categories.then((data) => {
      dispatch(receiveCategories(data));
    });
  });
};
export const fetchSingleProduct = (productId) => ({
  type: types.FETCH_SINGLE_PRODUCT,
  productId,
});
export const fetchSingleCategory = (categoryId) => ({
  type: types.FETCH_SINGLE_PRODUCT,
  categoryId,
});

//it seems that I should probably use this as the basis for "Cart"
export const addToCart = (product, qty) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.success("Item Added to Cart");
  dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(product, qty));
};
export const addToCartAndRemoveWishlist = (product, qty) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.success("Item Added to Cart");
  dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(product, qty));
  dispatch(removeFromWishlist(product));
};
export const addToCartUnsafe = (product, qty) => ({
  type: types.ADD_TO_CART,
  product,
  qty,
});
export const removeFromCart = (product_id) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.error("Item Removed from Cart");
  dispatch({
    type: types.REMOVE_FROM_CART,
    product_id,
  });
};
export const incrementQty = (product, qty) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.success("Item Added to Cart");
  dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(product, qty));
};
export const decrementQty = (productId) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.warn("Item Decrement Qty to Cart");

  dispatch({
    type: types.DECREMENT_QTY,
    productId,
  });
};

//it seems that I should probably use this as the basis for "Wishlist"
export const addToWishlist = (product) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.success("Item Added to Wishlist");
  dispatch(addToWishlistUnsafe(product));
};
export const addToWishlistUnsafe = (product) => ({
  type: types.ADD_TO_WISHLIST,
  product,
});
export const removeFromWishlist = (product_id) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.error("Item Removed from Wishlist");
  dispatch({
    type: types.REMOVE_FROM_WISHLIST,
    product_id,
  });
};

//Compare Products
export const addToCompare = (product) => (dispatch) => {
  toast.success("Item Added to Compare");
  dispatch(addToCompareUnsafe(product));
};
export const addToCompareUnsafe = (product) => ({
  type: types.ADD_TO_COMPARE,
  product,
});
export const removeFromCompare = (product_id) => ({
  type: types.REMOVE_FROM_COMPARE,
  product_id,
});

// Filters
export const filterBrand = (brand) => ({
  type: types.FILTER_BRAND,
  brand,
});
export const filterColor = (color) => ({
  type: types.FILTER_COLOR,
  color,
});
export const filterPrice = (value) => ({
  type: types.FILTER_PRICE,
  value,
});
export const filterSort = (sort_by) => ({
  type: types.SORT_BY,
  sort_by,
});

// Currency
export const changeCurrency = (symbol) => ({
  type: types.CHANGE_CURRENCY,
  symbol,
});
```

**reducer/categories.js:**

```
import { RECEIVE_CATEGORIES } from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const initialState = {
  category: [],
};

const categoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_CATEGORIES:
      return { ...state, categories: action.categories };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default categoryReducer;
```

**reducer/index.js:**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { IntlReducer as Intl, IntlProvider } from "react-redux-multilingual";

// Import custom components
import productReducer from "./products";
import categories from "./categories";
import cartReducer from "./cart";
import filtersReducer from "./filters";
import wishlistReducer from "./wishlist";
import compareReducer from "./compare";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  data: productReducer,
  categories,
  cartList: cartReducer,
  filters: filtersReducer,
  wishlist: wishlistReducer,
  compare: compareReducer,
  Intl,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Are you getting response in postman? try to call the api in postman and check?

Comment: Have you wrapped your App with the Redux Provider? I can not see the file that call the Category component.

Comment: yeah i have done that in index.js file